# Conversion from `java.time.Instant` to `java.util.Date` adds UTC offset

Tags: java, java.util.date

I seem to misunderstand `java.util.Date`'s conversion from and to `java.time.Instance`. I have some legacy code I need to ineract with, and this code uses `java.util.Date` in its API.

I am slightly confused when offsets are added in the `Date` API. It was my understand that `Date` is a UTC time ("the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC)"), but when I create a `Date` from an `Instant` an offset is added:

```
public class TestDateInstant {
    @Test
    public void instantdate() {
        Instant i = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(i);
        Date d = Date.from(i);
        System.out.println(d);

        assertThat(i, equalTo(d.toInstant()));
    }
}
```

The assertion holds, but the output on the console is:

```
2017-09-26T08:24:40.858Z 
Tue Sep 26 10:24:40 CEST 2017
```

I am wondering why `Date.from` uses an offset in this case.

Comment: `Date.from` does not use an offset. The offset is applied when *printing* the `Date` value.

Comment: Useful article to understand what's happening: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Date` or `Instant` both are NOT specific to a timezone.
The difference is when you print them.

`Instant.toString()` prints in ISO-8601 representation in UTC timezone.

`Date.toString()` prints it in your current timezone.

That's why you see the difference.

Comment: When I print d.getHour() it also returns the hour with the offset instead og the UTC hour.

Comment: This is not true. `java.util.Date` contains `ZoneOffset` and `ZoneInfo` fields.